# MySql: Lock with no effect?

Tags: mysql

I have a table "offers" which contains "orders" as well. An offer can be changed into a "order" by adding a unique incremental order-number.

I do:

```
$DB->Sql("SELECT GET_LOCK('ORDERNO')");
$n = $DB->resultSql("SELECT max(orderno) FROM orders");
$n += 1;
$DB->Sql("UPDATE orders SET orderno=".$n." WHERE id=".$actualId);
$DB->Sql("SELECT RELEASE_LOCK('ORDERNO')");
```

But resently, I got two identical order-numbers.

I want to avoid using

```
SELECT max(orderno) FOR UPDATE
```

because this blocks the whole table, and the orderno is ONLY set in this part of the code so my idea was to use LOCKS to make everything faster.

Any idea why it was possible to get the same number twice?

Comment: AUTO_INCREMENT should be enough.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How is it done with AUTO_INCREMENT? NULL has to be a possible value as well, so how do I switch from NULL to the next max value?

Comment: `SELECT 1+orderno as orderno FROM orders ORDER BY orderno DESC LIMIT 1` ..instead of `MAX()` ..

Comment: @Werner Why do you want to store `NULL`? How about adding boolean column like `IS_CONFIRMED` or something similiar?

Comment: Are you using MyISAM or InnoDB? If you're using InnoDB you should use transactions.

Comment: @lad2025 `AUTO_INCREMENT` can only be used with the primary key. That would presumably be the `id` column, not `order_no`.

Comment: I'm using InnoDB, but with transactions the whole table would be locked as far as I understood it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a single update statement:

```
update orders t
cross join (select max(orderno) as maxno from orders) x
set t.orderno = x.maxno + 1
where id = ?;
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/GEJHX43916

This way you don't need to lock anything manually.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Whats the difference between your solution and a subquery like: UPDATE orders set orderno=(SELECT max(orderno)+1 FROM orders) WHERE id=?;

Comment: @Werner This won't work this way (try it). As workaround you will need to wrap the subquery into a subquery: `orderno=(SELECT*FROM(SELECT max(orderno)+1 FROM orders)x) WHERE id=?`. Then there would be no difference which I know of.